# Are there any APIs for financial pattern recognition?

Tags: machine-learning, finance

I have seen [this question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/16347) on the site, however it is asking for the techniques that can be used for implementation. The thing I want to know is that, on the other hand, if are there any **APIs or services for financial pattern recognition**, i.e. capable of finding particular patterns that occur in a given set of data?

*Think like that:* I supply the data and if there are head-and-shoulders patterns detected in it; the API returns the index of the left/right shoulder etc.